# Is there a way to get clicked element on blur or focusout event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, target, blur

How to know where was click on blur or focusout of my input?

I've sketched a small example:

Html:

```
<div id ="all">
    <div id="whereIsInput">
        <input id="blur"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#whereIsInput{
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: yellow; 
}
```

JS:

```
function onBlur(e){
    jQuery('#all').append('<div>' + e.type + ', ' + e.target.toString() + '</div>')    
}
jQuery('#blur').blur(onBlur);
jQuery('body').on('click', onBlur);
```

So questions is: **where was click when blur is occured?**

I've investigate this: 
1. can't find it in blur or focusout event arguments
2. click on body occurs later then blur

Comment: AFAIR `bind()` is deprecated, `on()` is suggested instead.

Comment: thanks! but it's does not help

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a flag to check if a blur event ocurred before click.

```
var blurred = false;//blur flag

$(document).on("click", function(){
    if(blurred){
        console.log(this);
        blurred = false;
    }
});

$("input#blur").on("blur", function(){
    blurred = true;//blur occurred
});
```